# How do you ensure that the number of objects from each model returned is the same?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm getting into a bit of a ruck. I have two models, Photo and Video. They both inherit from an Item model. I call `Photo.objects.all()` and `Video.objects.all()` and I group them into a list. Then, I use a for statement to display them. However, I have 100 video objects and 1000 photo objects. Since there are much fewer video objects than photo objects, how would I ensure that the video objects are equally balanced among the photo objects?

For Example, I'd like item 1, 2, 4, 5 in my list to be photos and item 3 and 6 to be videos. I really don't want to have videos clumping together. How would I ensure this kind of balanced ratio? I understand that eventually since photo objects outnumber video objects they'd have to clump, but I'd like my initial pagination pages to have a relatively balanced amount of photos and videos.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
  photos = Photos.objects.all()
   videos = Videos.objects.all()
   if photos.count() != videos.count():
          #some stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a two-list merge feature.
You can do it like this.

```
photos = Photos.objects.all()
videos = Videos.objects.all()
step = photos.count() / videos.count()
display_list = list(photos)
pos = 0
# insert videos into display_list
for v in videos:
    display_list.insert(pos, v)
    pos += step + 1
```